# JavaFX coordinate inside scrollpane

Tags: java, javafx, scrollbar, jscrollpane, javafx-8

I have various object organized Inside a Vbox it works pretty well. I can access coordinate of each object by using the getter on layoutX/Y like this

```
myObject.getlayoutY() // for example
```

Now I put the Vbox Inside a Scrollpane to allow scrolling on the Vbox so I have this configuration :

```
<ScrollPane>
<content>
    <VBox>
        <children>
            <myobject1/>
             ....
            <myobjectN/>

        </children>
    </VBox>
</content>
```

It Works pretty well to but here the issue : I don't understand what it's moving Inside the scrollpane.

When i try to user getlayoutY() on the Vbox or on myObject I have a constant value even if I scroll.

How Can I access easyly the new coordinate of my object realively to the scroll value ??

**EDIT** : I want to transform in coordinate system of the parent of the scrollpane

Note : I manage to acess scrollbar value (between [0-1]) and I can use the getLocalToSceneTransform() to access the coordinate but I think i am on the wrong way.

Comment: `getLayoutY()` gives you the layout coordinates of the child relative to its parent (the `VBox`). Since it isn't moving relative to the `VBox`, that value is not going to change. (Note that the layout coordinates are not the only things that determine the location of a node.) The scroll pane is going to move its content - the `VBox` - relative to itself, and consequently all its ancestors in the scene graph. Transforming to the scene coordinate system is a good start, but you need to specify which coordinate system you are actually interested in (presumably some parent node of the scroll pane)

Comment: (In short, the `VBox` is moving inside the scroll pane. The children of the `VBox` are not moving relative to the `VBox`.)

Comment: So why getlayoutY on the Vbox doesn't change anymore ?? For the coordinate system that's a good point i want to compare coordinate of myobject to object that are "brother" of the scrollpane

Comment: I think the `ScrollPane` works by translating its content and then clipping it (though I'm not entirely certain that's correct). Translations are applied after the layout (i.e. layout bounds don't include translations). You can always convert bounds to the scene coordinate system, and then convert from the scene coordinate system to the coordinate system of another node, using `localToScene(...)` and then `sceneToLocal(...)`. I'll post an example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the following example helps achieve what you want:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BindToScrollingObject extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        ScrollPane scroller = new ScrollPane();
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        scroller.setContent(vbox);
        Label bindingLabel = new Label("Binding here");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            vbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Item "+(i+1)));
        }
        vbox.getChildren().add(bindingLabel);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            vbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Item "+(i+6)));
        }
        Label anchor = new Label("Anchor");
        anchor.setStyle("-fx-background-color: antiquewhite");
        StackPane stack = new StackPane(anchor);

        root.getChildren().addAll(scroller, stack);

        Line line = new Line();
        line.setManaged(false);
        root.getChildren().add(line);

        ChangeListener<Object> listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
            updateLine(line, anchor, bindingLabel);

        anchor.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener(listener);
        anchor.localToSceneTransformProperty().addListener(listener);
        bindingLabel.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener(listener);
        bindingLabel.localToSceneTransformProperty().addListener(listener);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void updateLine(Line line, Node start, Node end) {

        Node target = line.getParent();

        Bounds startBounds = convertBoundsToTarget(start, target);
        Bounds endBounds = convertBoundsToTarget(end, target);


        line.setStartX(startBounds.getMinX() + startBounds.getWidth() / 2);
        line.setStartY(startBounds.getMinY() + startBounds.getHeight() / 2);
        line.setEndX(endBounds.getMinX() + endBounds.getWidth() / 2);
        line.setEndY(endBounds.getMinY() + endBounds.getHeight() / 2);
    }

    private Bounds convertBoundsToTarget(Node node, Node target) {
        Bounds boundsInScene = node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal());
        return target.sceneToLocal(boundsInScene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed that the localToScene and sceneToLocal transform is very slow. Are they any other way to do the same thing for almost sibling node Inside a deepHierarchy ?